# Sempre que executo o app, ele fecha sozinho

Tags: java, android-studio, app

Boa tarde, estou com um problema e não consigo resolver. Toda vez que eu tento testar o app no celular ele fecha sozinho:

Logcat: 
2020-05-09 16:02:58.397 30691-30691/com.leandrel.uri E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.leandrel.uri, PID: 30691
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{d676bdc VFED..CL. .F...... 552,916-901,1092 #7f070037 app:id/edtNmr}"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.leandrel.uri.MainActivity.verificar(MainActivity.java:23)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 
2020-05-09 16:02:58.476 30691-30691/com.leandrel.uri I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30691 SIG: 9

O código em Java:

```
 package com.leandrel.uri;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            EditText nmr = findViewById(R.id.edtNmr);
        }

        public void verificar(View view) {
            EditText nmr = findViewById(R.id.edtNmr);
            String conv = String.valueOf(nmr);
            int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(conv);
            int i = 0, soma = 0;
            TextView result = findViewById(R.id.txvResult);
            for(i=1;i<inteiro;i++){
                if(i%inteiro==0){
                    soma += i;
                }
            }
            if(soma==inteiro){

                result.setText("O número "+inteiro+" é perfeito");
            }else{

                result.setText("O número "+inteiro+" não é perfeito");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tente melhorar a estrutura do seu código, deixando legível/fácil para você e outros no futuro.

Pelo que vi, você chama essa função **verificar()** a partir do clique em um botão certo? E ela recebe como parâmetro uma **view**.
Também faça uso de **Try-Catch** ou crie suas próprias exceções para facilitar a leitura do erro no **logcat**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//region Variaveis das suas views
private EditText nmr;
private TextView result;
private Button seuBotaoDeAcao;
//endregion

//region Strings
private String TAG = "MainActivity";
//endregion

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //region Referência das views
    nmr                 = findViewById(R.id.edtNmr);
    result              = findViewById(R.id.txvResult);
    seuBotaoDeAcao      = findViewById(R.id.seu_botao_acao);
    //endregion

    //region Ação do seuBotaoDeAcao
    seuBotaoDeAcao.setOnClickListener(v -> verificar(nmr.getText().toString().replaceAll(" ", "")));
    //endregion

}

private void verificar(String conv) {
    try{
        int inteiro = Integer.parseInt(conv);
        int soma = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < inteiro; i++){
            if(i%inteiro == 0) soma += i;
        }

        String result = soma == inteiro ? "é perfeito" : "não é perfeito";
        result.setText("O número "+inteiro+" "+result);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG,"Erro na função verificar: "+ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}